# Can Squid cause my pages to not use the latest file?

Tags: squid

I just setup a wordpress blog and I am having a really hard time editing templates.  The problem is that I will edit a template and upload the new version, refresh the page and some of the updated template files work and some are still showing the old file, at first I though maybe I uploaded the wrong file but I even downloaded the file from my server, edited it, and reupload it back to the server with FTP and someone the changes I make do not show up in the actual file at all.  I am using a shared hosting environment for this and I know they use Squid, could it be that squid is affecting this?  If so is there a way to get my file to upload and work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that Wordpress considers a template change to be enough to change the last modified date of a webpage.

To test that Squid is at fault, add "?rand=6987099" to the end of your url. It should force the change to come through. As a bit of a workaround, you can change the number every time it gets stuck in your cache.

Alternatively, add an admin link to the template which generates you a random number that you can click on to reload.